# Reactjs memory leaks - inline functions vs. bound curried functions

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, currying

A coworker and I were discussing in-lined functions within the render call leading to memory leaks. I suggested we bind a curried function, but he argued it would produce the same effect. Is this true? Does currying produce memory leaks due to a new function getting created each render call?

Is there a better way to use currying that doesn't lead to memory leaks?

**Additional kudos to those who provide good reading material on this topic.**

Simple Example demonstrating the two approaches in question.

```
export default class ParentComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            memLeak: false,
        };

        this.curryExample = this.curryExample.bind(this);
    }

    curryExample(bool) {
        return () => {
            this.setState({memLeak: bool})
        };
    }

    render() {
        const {memLeak} = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                {/* inline func leads to memory leaks */}
                <ChildComponent onClick={() => this.setState({memLeak: !memLeak})}/>

                {/* but does a bound function to Parent scope do the same?? */}
                <ChildComponent onClick={this.curryExample(!memLeak)}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [React's discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12141) about "memory leaks" re issue above.

Turns out, they aren't memory leaks per se. Additional event handlers get created in *DEV* that *ultimately* get garbage collected. So, more GC runs in dev, but no memory leaks that will end up bringing your app to a halt.

So - this discussion was a moot point. Cheers!